# Org Babel: Possible to get Python shell with session?

Tags: org-babel, python

When I make an Org Babel shell code block with for instance a `:session a` header argument, it automatically makes a buffer `a` with the shell for this session, so I can explore it interactively.

This is a great feature. Is it possible to get the same behavior with Python blocks as well? It doesn't seem to happen automatically for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel evaluation of python code blocks is peculiar: using `:session foo` and `:results output` behaves most closely to what you would expect (assuming you don't expect too much...). The evaluation buffer would be `*foo*` in the above case (or `*Python*` if you don't specify a session name). See https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html for some (incomplete) details, but you'll need to experiment to figure out what is going on - and be prepared for some head-scratching in the process.

But you can certainly expore it interactively. Here for example is what I get when I evaluate a python code block and then switch to the session buffer for some interactive work. First, the Org mode file:

```org
#+begin_src python :results output :session one
  def foo(x):
    if x>0:
      return x+2
    else:
      return x-2

  print(foo(1))
  print(foo(-1))
#+end_src
```

Then after evaluating the block with `C-c C-c`, I can switch to buffer `*one*` where I find this (note that I use Ipython as my interactive shell because I have set `python-shell-interpreter` to `ipython'):

```
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  3 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 13.2.1 20230728 (Red Hat 13.2.1-1)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: 
3
-3
org_babel_python_eoe

In [6]:
```

and then I can proceed to evaluate things interactively there:

```
Python 3.11.6 (main, Oct  3 2023, 00:00:00) [GCC 13.2.1 20230728 (Red Hat 13.2.1-1)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.9.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: 
3
-3
org_babel_python_eoe

In [6]: foo
Out[6]: <function __main__.foo(x)>

In [7]: foo(5)
Out[7]: 7

In [8]: foo(-10)
Out[8]: -12

In [9]: bar
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 bar

NameError: name 'bar' is not defined

In [10]:
```

The babel evaluation created the buffer, started the interpreter, evaluated the code block which defined the function `foo` and printed out the two numbers. The rest I typed by hand in the session buffer.